# OS X: Where do environment variables get loaded from?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I have an env var that's being set(PYTHONPATH) whenever I open a new Bash shell, but I don't see any reference to the variable in ~/* or /etc/*. Where could this variable be set from?

Comment: why has this question been migrated? It's not related to programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.  `*` doesn't match files starting with `.` (hidden files).

Comment: It was in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist